# Accept all incoming email, send messages from multiple identities

Tags: email, smtp, spam, qmail

I am working on a research project that has to do with responding to spam. I want to implement the following functionality:
1. A mail server that saves all incoming email messages in an easily accessable form - hard drive, database, etc. For example, if someone sends a message to peter@domain.com or akjfhasfkjf@domain.com, this message should be accepted and saved.
2. I should be able to reply to these messages from the same server/account. E.g. a message gets delivered to peter@domain.com, so the spammer receives a response from the same address.

Any suggestions on any software / packages that can help me with that? If I can interface with them with Java or Python, it would be even better.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you could run a postfix mailserver with [fuglu](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/fuglu/),a python framework for mail filters. it would be very simple to write a plugin that does what you want.

but remember: responding to spam is in most cases a bad idea. the sender address is almost always forged, so the reply goes some innocent victim instead of the spammers inbox and your server could be blacklisted for [backscattering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backscatter_%28e-mail%29).